# MapStateToProps depends on props of component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have components like this

```
export class Parent extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        let {items} = this.props;
        return <React.Fragment>
            {items.map((item, index) => <Child index={index} name={item.name}/>)}
        </React.Fragment>
    }

}

class Child extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {
        let {index, name} = this.props;
        return <div>{`index = ${index} name=${name}`}</div>
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Child);
```

How can I get "index" param from Child component inside mapStateToProps? I want to make props which depend on this param. Or maybe is it bad practice and I have to do this other way?

Answer (score 6):

There is a second, optional argument to `mapStateToProps`, ownProps. That should be what you need.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  }
}
```